# jQuery - Checking if -data element exist in array with each() and inArray()

Tags: jquery, each

my goal is to check if any -data (data-id) on site have same value as one of elements in array but inArray always returns -1

```
 <a href="#" data-id="2">
 <a href="#" data-id="3">

<script>
var arrayObjects = <?php echo $json_array; ?>;
console.log(arrayObjects);

$("[data-id]").each(function(){
    var data_id = $(this).data('id');

    if(jQuery.inArray(data_id, arrayObjects) > -1) { // f
        console.log(data_id);
        console.log('found');
    } else { // nf
        console.log(data_id);
        console.log('not found');
    }
});
```

From my console:

```
["2", "3"]
3
not found
2
not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you retrieve the **data-id** `var data_id = $(this).data("id")`, you get a *Number*, whereas the **arrayObjects** contains *Strings* !

Here, check this [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c02b4hxv/4/) you'll see that the `console.log(typeof(data_id))` is Number. To get this work, just add `""+` to force the **data_id** to be a String :

<s>`jQuery.inArray(""+data_id, arrayObjects)`</s>

## Update:

As @barmar pointed out, `var data_id = $(this).attr('data-id')` fits better as the *.attr()* method will return a **string**, *.data()* parse the data as JSON, giving a **number** in our case.

No more trick forcing the type to string

`jQuery.inArray(data_id, arrayObjects)`

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)
Please consider putting the answer as Accepted for other readers !

Comment: FYI, the reason this happens is because `.data()` parses the data as JSON. If you use `.attr('data-id')` you'll get a string.

Comment: That's a good point , i changed to attr for a sake of neatness